# Why is my Wordpress install using full server directory paths for media URLs?

Tags: urls

So I have this Wordpress blog at [ilovetheupperwestside.com](http://ilovetheupperwestside.com). It uses the Aggregate Theme from Elegant Themes.
I moved it from a temporary location to the current URL.

This action broke some things, but thanks to a plugin called "Velvet Blues Update URLs" and a (serialization safe) database search & replace script nearly everything was fixed. One problem seems to still remain.

Media paths that are generated by Wordpress are server directory paths, example [from this article](http://ilovetheupperwestside.com/magic-of-morningside-heights/):

```
<div class="thumb"> 

<img src="/home/sear9635/public_html/uwsb/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/morningside-heights-amsterdam-960-166604_200x200.jpg" class='single-thumb'  alt='The Magic of Morningside Heights' width='200px' height='200px' />                     

<span class="overlay"></span>

</div>  
<!-- end .thumb -->
```

The file in question is a new file which I just uploaded. The thumbnail was generated by Wordpress with the faulty URL. This seems to occur with all media content.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by editing "custom_functions.php" within my theme, it was a bug that occurs when updating some Elegant themes.

Instructions here:

http://www.agentwp.com/fix-thumbnails-not-working-in-a-wordpress-theme-from-elegant-themes

Answer (score 0):

look for wp-app.php and MEDIA_SINGLE_PATH

Comment: wp-app.php seems to be identical Wordpress' current default.
Will look into MEDA_SINGLE_PATH, so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Go to Settings -> Media and make sure that the media folder is set up properly. Is it set to save to a custom folder - the server path you indicated?
2. If that's not it, it might be worth attempting the migration again with a tool like BackupBuddy or, if you don't have that, then by simply dumping the old database, dropping all the tables from the new DB and importing it again - then making sure to set the new URL [using the wp-config.php file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Then you could use the search/replace plugin to replace only absolute URLs within posts, links and such.

9 times out of 10, that will resolve migration problems right away.